# sympy: решение системы линейных уравнений

Tags: python, sympy

Надо в символьном виде решить систему линейных уравнений. Я запрограммировал автоматическое создание системы линейных уравнений, количество уравнений определяется числом n (заранее задано). Переменные тоже задал.

Получается следующее:

```
##########  система линейных уравнений ##########

[-mui0*exp(Ea0**2/(T0*k)) - mui0*exp(Ea1**2/(T0*k)) - mui0*exp(Ea2**2/(T0*k))
 - mui0*exp(Ea3**2/(T0*k)) + (Eb0**2/(T0*k) - 2*Ec0)*exp(Ea0**2/(T0*k))
 + (Eb1**2/(T0*k) - 2*Ec1)*exp(Ea1**2/(T0*k)) + (Eb2**2/(T0*k)
 - 2*Ec2)*exp(Ea2**2/(T0*k)) + (Eb3**2/(T0*k) - 2*Ec3)*exp(Ea3**2/(T0*k)),
 -mui1*exp(Ea0**2/(T1*k)) - mui1*exp(Ea1**2/(T1*k)) - mui1*exp(Ea2**2/(T1*k))
 - mui1*exp(Ea3**2/(T1*k)) + (Eb0**2/(T1*k) - 2*Ec0)*exp(Ea0**2/(T1*k))
 + (Eb1**2/(T1*k) - 2*Ec1)*exp(Ea1**2/(T1*k)) + (Eb2**2/(T1*k)
 - 2*Ec2)*exp(Ea2**2/(T1*k)) + (Eb3**2/(T1*k) - 2*Ec3)*exp(Ea3**2/(T1*k)),
 -mui2*exp(Ea0**2/(T2*k)) - mui2*exp(Ea1**2/(T2*k)) - mui2*exp(Ea2**2/(T2*k))
 - mui2*exp(Ea3**2/(T2*k)) + (Eb0**2/(T2*k) - 2*Ec0)*exp(Ea0**2/(T2*k))
 + (Eb1**2/(T2*k) - 2*Ec1)*exp(Ea1**2/(T2*k)) + (Eb2**2/(T2*k)
 - 2*Ec2)*exp(Ea2**2/(T2*k)) + (Eb3**2/(T2*k) - 2*Ec3)*exp(Ea3**2/(T2*k)),
 -mui3*exp(Ea0**2/(T3*k)) - mui3*exp(Ea1**2/(T3*k)) - mui3*exp(Ea2**2/(T3*k))
 - mui3*exp(Ea3**2/(T3*k)) + (Eb0**2/(T3*k) - 2*Ec0)*exp(Ea0**2/(T3*k))
 + (Eb1**2/(T3*k) - 2*Ec1)*exp(Ea1**2/(T3*k)) + (Eb2**2/(T3*k)
 - 2*Ec2)*exp(Ea2**2/(T3*k)) + (Eb3**2/(T3*k) - 2*Ec3)*exp(Ea3**2/(T3*k))]

###### переменные ###### 

[Ea0, Ea1, Ea2, Ea3, Ea4, Eb0, Eb1, Eb2, Eb3, Eb4, Ec0, Ec1, Ec2, Ec3, Ec4]
```

Теперь, когда я пишу `a = linsolve(list_eq,list_var)`, появляется ошибка:

```
SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '[''
failed, because of exception being raised:
TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
```

Как быть, чтобы SymPy находил решение системы линейных уравнений?

вот мой полный код (надеюсь при вставке сюда, код сохранил спайдеровские отступы):

```
from sympy import exp,symbols
from sympy import Float,linsolve

def chis_znam_construct(T,i_eq,n):

    En1 = symbols('Eb:' + str(n+1))
    En0 = symbols('Ea:' + str(n+1))
    En2 = symbols('Ec:' + str(n+1))
    mui = symbols('mui:' + str(n+1))
    k = symbols('k')
    chis=0
    znam=0
    i_levels=0
    eq=[]
    varS=[]
    dictvanfleck=dict({})
    dictvanfleck['eq']=[]        
    dictvanfleck['vars']=[]

def getvars(f,varS):
    i_var=0
    while i_var<=(len(f)-1):
        varS.append(f[i_var])
        i_var+=1
    return varS
variable=getvars(En0,varS)
variable=getvars(En1,varS)
variable=getvars(En2,varS)

for i_levels in range(n):
    chis+=((En1[i_levels]**2)/(k*T)- 
          (En2[i_levels]+En2[i_levels]))*exp((En0[i_levels]**2)/(k*T))
    znam+=mui[i_eq]*exp((En0[i_levels]**2)/(k*T))
    i_levels+=1
print('')
print('')
eq.append(chis-znam)
dictvanfleck['vars']=variable
dictvanfleck['eq']=eq
return dictvanfleck


def eq_construct(T,n):
    i_eq=0
    eq=[]
    for i_eq in range(n):
        eq.append(chis_znam_construct(T[i_eq],i_eq,n))
        i_eq+=1
    return eq 

print('')
print('')

def solve_eq(T,n):
    equations=eq_construct(T,n)
    eqA=equations[1]
    var=eqA['vars']
    i=0
    equat=[]
    while i<=(n-1):
        eqA=equations[i]
        eqq=eqA['eq']
        equat.append(eqq[0])
        i+=1
    list_eq=str(equat)
    list_var=str(var)
    print('')
    print('list_eq',list_eq)
    print('')
    print('list_var',list_var)
    a = linsolve(list_eq,list_var)
    return a 

n = 4
T = symbols('T:' + str(n+1))
equations=solve_eq(T,n)
```

нужны ли какие-то еще построчные комментарии ?

mui and T являются экспериментальными данными ; а переменные : En0, En1, En2 - надо найти

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но у вас же неизвестные под экспонентами. Какое же это СЛАУ?

Comment: Приведите весь код, включая импорты и т.д. Со скобками у вас вроде всё нормально, я проверил, а других вариантов в голову не приходит.